# Error when deploying to WildFly: "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory"

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I keep seeing this error when I try to deploy my Java EE application to WildFly 15.0.1.Final.

I see that org.apache.directory.api::api-all [depends on](https://github.com/apache/directory-ldap-api/blob/b228f52cc8806e4a38719e9a5467c2726ef1422b/pom.xml#L602-L606) org.apache.servicemix.bundles::org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j, and the latter dependency [depends on](https://github.com/apache/servicemix-bundles/blob/97f5476ecd901210a37146b467e6c1e2151dfc91/dom4j-2.1.1/pom.xml#L71-L85) org.dom4j::dom4j. On the other hand, my WildFly installation has dom4j-2.1.1.jar in modules/system/layers/base/org/dom4j/main/

I tried various things in my pom.xml, for example with org.apache.servicemix.bundles::org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j and org.dom4j::dom4j, excluding each of them and specifying the "provoided" scope. Nothing worked.

Here is the snippet from my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <finalWarName>ldapuserimport</finalWarName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.26</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>27.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Could you suggest how to solve this issue please?

Comment: Look at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-5549?_sscc=t

Comment: @TechFree I saw that. I don't have hibernate dependency in pom.xml. I tried adding jboss-deployment-structure.xml but this didn't help.

Comment: Both `org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec` and `javax.persistence:persistence-api` should be marked with `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: I ended up deleting these `org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec` and `javax.persistence:persistence-api`, as well as `org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec`, as they turned out to be unnecessary. The problem unexpectedly came back again after deleting the <deployments>-section. What finally solved the issue was excluding `org.apache.servicemix.bundle:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j` from `org.apache.directory.api:api-all` and adding the dependency `org.dom4j:dom4j` (version 2.1.1). Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

One of your dependencies has dom4j old version and server uses that version. Try this command for your dependencies to see which one uses old dom4j version

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections
```

After that exclude dom4j from that dependency in your dependency tag.

```
 <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
```

Or try to use newer version of the dependency that has old version dependency of dom4j

Comment: Your command showed that org.apache.directory.api:api-all uses commons-collections:commons-collections. When I ran "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.dom4j", it showed that nothing depends on org.dom4j. I tried excluding org.dom4j from org.apache.directory.api:api-all before creating this topic but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by deleting these 2 lines

```
<deployments>
</deployments>
```

in standalone.xml in WildFly. This version of standalone.xml was created from standalone.xml from the previous installation of WildFly, in which things worked ealier, by deleting everything except what is necessary (namely, datasource- and driver- sections).

Weird.